# Was The Who's album 'Quadrophenia' actually quadraphonic?

Tags: sound

[*Quadrophenia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrophenia) was available on vinyl with stereo playback (and probably mono too, but I have only seen stereo copies).

If it was quadraphonic, why was it sold on vinyl appropriate for stereo playback? What would that offer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quadrophenia was not meant to be quadrophonic.  Quadrophenia deals with a boy (Jimmy) who has split personalities (see any similarities to Green Day's "American Idiot" here?).  Each personality was meant to be assumed by the 4 members of The Who.  To quote [the Wiki on the album](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrophenia):

> To illustrate the four-way split personality of Jimmy, Townshend wrote
>   four themes, reflecting the four members of the Who. These were "Bell
>   Boy" (Moon), "Is It Me?" (Entwistle), "Helpless Dancer" (Daltrey) and
>   "Love Reign O'er Me" (Townshend). Two lengthy instrumentals on the
>   album, the title track and "The Rock" contain the four themes,
>   separately and together.

Gotta love those old concept albums, and the way the material was tied together.  :o)

Comment: The modern medical term for this condition is "dissociative identity disorder". Previously it was referred to as "multiple personality disorder" or "split personalities".

Answer (score 4):

While the album *Quadrophenia* was not recorded as quadrophonic, that was the first (and only) Who tour that was produced with quadrophonic sound. I saw it in Philly in 1973 (Dec. 4, I think).  They had speaker columns set up in the back corners of The Spectrum. On the recording made for the *King Biscuit Flower Hour*, you can clearly hear Pete Townshend end his introduction of the album with the phrase "quadrophonic, of course . . ."

Incidentally, that same year I saw Pink Floyd for the first time.  *The Dark Side of the Moon* tour was also done in quadrophonic sound.  And virtually every Floyd concert since then - and every Roger Waters tour too - has kept the quadrophonic sound for live performances.

Answer (score 0):

Townshend initially wanted the Quadrophenia album to be released in quadrophonic sound, but he was dissatisfied with the existing quad technology. So he worked with studio engineer Ron Nevision and the who's on the road engineer Bob Pridden to build a studio capable of producing the kind of quadrophonic sound he wanted to achieve. However, they kept tearing and rebuilding the studio several times never adequately reaching their goal. Pressed for time on delivering a finished studio album, Townshend opted to release the l.p. in standard stereo. I have heard the album on a pioneer quad amp which is capable of creating a "quad" sound. It sounds good. However, there is now a 5.1. quad surround sound mix of Quadrophenia on vinyl l.p. now and I suppose that is about as true to Pete's original vision of a quad mix that were going to see in the present.

Answer (score 0):

Quadrophenia was one of the few LPs released in quadrophonic format. I had a copy back then. I have no idea if it was recorded in quad or just mastered for the format. So yes is the answer.